# rename windows files - reformat date

Tags: windows, file, rename

I have hundreds of files (pictures) that were loaded with the date as part of the name.  However, the file names are currently in the format "MM-DD-YY xxxxxxxx.jpg".  I would like to rename them to the format "YYYY-MM-DD xxxxxxxxx.jpg", so they can sort better.

Any ideas?  I'm running Windows 10.

Thank you,
Luis

Answer (score 0):

1. Select all the files you want to rename from one date.
2. Eg : Select all pictures that were taken on `17-10-2016`.
3. Hit `F2` to rename.
4. Now enter the new date format ( i.e `2016-10-17` in our case ).
5. After reanaming, Hit `Enter`.
6. All your files are renamed into the format in which you need.

   Similarly, do it for pictures with similar dates.